# Cannot login into my Prestashop site admin

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, prestashop

I am trying to login into my Prestashop admin.

1. When use forgot password link it says =>employee does not exist
2. I try to change in phpMyAdmin ps_employee  table  after changing when I try to login it again gives error => 1.employee does not exist, or bad password

Answer (score 2):

You can save the result of the next query in the passwd field of the ps_employee table:

```
SELECT MD5(CONCAT("your cookie key","your new pass"))
```

The cookie key value is defined in 'config\settings.inc.php'

Answer (score 0):

yet another way to change the password under linux:
to generate new md5 hash, from your prestashop folder:

```
echo -ne `cat config/settings.inc.php | grep _COOKIE_KEY | cut -d "'" -f 4`password | md5sum
```

copy the resulting hash into `passwd` column of the `ps_employee` (`ps_` is the prefix you set during install, it can be something different) relevant to your user